# What will happen if I use some iOS5 features but the deployment target is a iOS4 device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am switching my SDK from iOS4 to iOS5, and I want to use some iOS5 features in my old iOS4 projects.

What will happen if I use some iOS5 features but the deployment target is a iOS4 device ?

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will just crash, most propably because of unrecognized selector.

to avoid this, you can fork the code with if()-statements

like

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@newiOS5Selector])
```

Also, you can read out the current iOS version via `UIDevice`

```
+(BOOL)platformSupportsVersion:(NSString *)requiredVersion
{
    float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (systemVersion >= [requiredVersion floatValue]) {
        return YES;
    } 

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Then I better stay away from the new features in my old projects, and split the projects into iOS4 and iOS5 versions.

Comment: you dont have to stay away from the features! you just need to support both versions in code via appropriate if-statements

Comment: i bumped my answer with example code to make it easy to support different platform versions

Answer (score -1):

That features will work only on devices with installed `iOS5` or later.

If you will call new `iOS5 API` on devices with previous versions of `iOS` (4.x) it will crash in that places.